# Set default configurable selection in Magento 2.1

Tags: product, configurable-product, magento-2.1

In Magento 2.1, there is no default selection for configurable products (swatches, etc).

I would like to automatically select when there is only one option currently available, to make the process less confusing for customers.

There is a resolution already for Magento 2 with edit of Magento_Swatches/templates/product/view/renderer.phtml, but it does not apply to version 2.1.

[image: image showing no default selection]

Answer (score 6):

**Just Override your swatch-renderer.js file into your themee and change `_init()` function same as below: (about line 209)**

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js**

Keep below code in swatch-renderer.js file, **I have modified _init() function of  $.widget('mage.SwatchRenderer') widget in below file,**

```
_init: function () {
            if (_.isEmpty(this.options.jsonConfig.images)) {
                this.options.useAjax = true;
                // creates debounced variant of _LoadProductMedia()
                // to use it in events handlers instead of _LoadProductMedia()
                this._debouncedLoadProductMedia = _.debounce(this._LoadProductMedia.bind(this), 500);
            }

            if (this.options.jsonConfig !== '' && this.options.jsonSwatchConfig !== '') {
                // store unsorted attributes
                this.options.jsonConfig.mappedAttributes = _.clone(this.options.jsonConfig.attributes);
                this._sortAttributes();
                this._RenderControls();

                //this is additional code for select first attribute value
                if (this.options.jsonConfig.attributes.length > 0) {
                    var selectswatch = this.element.find('.' + this.options.classes.attributeClass + ' .' + this.options.classes.attributeOptionsWrapper);
                    $.each(selectswatch, function (index, item) {
                        var swatchOption = $(item).find('div.swatch-option').first();
                        if (swatchOption.length && !$(item).find('div.swatch-option').hasClass('selected')) {
                            swatchOption.trigger('click');
                        }
                    });
                }

                this._setPreSelectedGallery();
                $(this.element).trigger('swatch.initialized');
            } else {
                console.log('SwatchRenderer: No input data received');
            }
            this.options.tierPriceTemplate = $(this.options.tierPriceTemplateSelector).html();
        },
```

Comment: Working but must add .product-add-form class otherwise it will cause a problem with sidebar filter swatches in category page

Comment: Yeah the swatch-renderer.js in Magento 2.2.3 is about 3 times as long as the function you posted. I'd lose quite a lot by replacing it!

Comment: While this works, it throws an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateData' of undefined`. Because at that point the gallery hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: The renderer in 2.2 has a method called `_onGalleryLoaded`. You can add the code snipped OP mentioned at the end of the function.

Comment: Hi @rakesh ca u please let me know for dorpdown?

Answer (score 1):

This code is working for color swatch attribute.

Using below code, first swatch are automatically selected after page load in details page,

you have to override file into your theme,

**app/design/frontend/Packagename/themename/Magento_Swatches/templates/product/view/renderer.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable */ ?>
<div class="swatch-opt"></div>
<script>
    require(["jquery", "jquery/ui", "swatchRenderer"], function ($) {
        $('.swatch-opt').SwatchRenderer({
            jsonConfig: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $swatchOptions = $block->getJsonConfig(); ?>,
            jsonSwatchConfig: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $swatchOptions = $block->getJsonSwatchConfig(); ?>,
            mediaCallback: '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getMediaCallback() ?>'
        });

        //for selected option if only one value is exist....
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            //for swatches1
            var swatchLength = $('.swatch-attribute').length;
            if(swatchLength >= 1){
                if($('.swatch-attribute').hasClass("color")){
                    $('.swatch-option').first().trigger('click');
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```