# Magento 2: How to set minimum amount option by default in product detail page for configurable options?

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.2.2

I want to auto select the lowest price options in product details page for configurable product in magento 2.

Tried to set the value using Jquery in product detail page.its not worked out.

Willing to get a method **configurable.js** file.

Comment: You can get idea from here:https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189088/magento-2-how-to-set-default-option-in-configurable-options