# Magento 2.3.4 - Configurable products auto select first option

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, configurable-swatches, configurable-product-options

On my clothing store, when I enter on product page of a configurable item, I need to auto-select the first option for color (swatch attribute).

I found this solution:
[How to make auto select first child product of configurable product in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232072/how-to-make-auto-select-first-child-product-of-configurable-product-in-magento2)

BUT don't works on Magento 2.3.4 because this file was removed!
--> module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/SwatchRenderer.js

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Refer this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189088/magento-2-how-to-set-default-option-in-configurable-options

Comment: As written, "SwatchRenderer.js" was removed on magento 2.3.4 !

Comment: Yes but there is a new file vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js. Check above link.

Comment: Just tried but nothing happens on my magento 2.3.4